# filepath plugin in cordova not working as it gives error

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

cordova-plugin-filepath not working.
error :"Unable to resolve filesystem path.".
cordova :12.0.0,
cordova-android: 12.0.0
jdk: 11.0.0
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.6.0 "cordova-plugin-filepath"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 2.0.0 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-file 8.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-filechooser 1.2.0 "File Chooser"

Can anyone help me out?